# How to perform a conditional lookup in r?

Tags: r

I play with the following two simple datasets:

```
(myData <- data.frame(ID=c(1:7, 5), Sum=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 700, 200)))
#   ID Sum
# 1  1  10
# 2  2  20
# 3  3  30
# 4  4  40
# 5  5  50
# 6  6  60
# 7  7 700
# 8  5 200
```

and

```
(myMap <- data.frame(ID=c(1:5, 7), Name=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g")))
#   ID  Name
# 1  1    a
# 2  2    b
# 3  3    c
# 4  4    d
# 5  5    e
# 6  7    g
```

I will map the data with the map, this way:

```
myData$Name<-myMap$Name[match(myData$ID, myMap$ID)]
```

However since there is no map entry for the `ID == 6`, the output is:

```
  ID Sum Name
1  1  10    a
2  2  20    b
3  3  30    c
4  4  40    d
5  5  50    e
6  6  60 <NA>
7  7 700    g
8  5 200    e
```

What I am trying to do now: in the record where `Name` is `NA`, the `Name` should become `ID`.
My attempts:

```
myData$Dummy<-ifelse( is.na(myData$Name),myData$ID, myData$Name)
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(myData$Name) )
  if (is.na(myData$Name[i])) 
  {
    x <- myData$ID[i]
    # print(x)
    myData$Name[i]<- as.factor(x)
    print(myData$Name[i])
  }
```

are wrong. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: You can try `myData$Name[is.na(myData$Name)] <- myData$ID[is.na(myData$Name)]` setting the names for the first time.

Comment: You didn't say what your `ifelse()` is producing that is wrong; perhaps it isn't working because `Name` is a factor. Try: `myData$Dummy<-ifelse(is.na(myData$Name), myData$ID, as.character(myData$Name))`

Comment: @Sam: `ifelse()` produced `1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5` in `Dummy` without any warning. Your code produced the necessary output, many thanks!

Comment: @Molx: your code produced a warnings: `invalid factor level, NA generated`, and `Name` is still with `NA` in the record 6.

Comment: That's because your column is a factor, like others mentioned. Either make them strings or use `levels(myData$Name) <- c(levels(myData$Name), myData$ID[is.na(myData$Name)])` to add the necessary IDs as factor levels, but that's not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the fact that the column you think is character is really a factor. Either use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data frame or you'll need to account for it when manipulating the data. I've provided `dplyr` + piping and base R solutions below. Note the use of `left_join` (`dplyr`) or `merge` (base) vs your subset & matching:

```
library(dplyr)

myData <- read.csv(text="ID;Sum
1;10
2;20
3;30
4;40
5;50
6;60
7;700
5;200", sep=";")

myMap <- read.csv(text="ID;Name
1;a
2;b
3;c
4;d
5;e
7;g", sep=";")

# dplyr -------------------------------------------------------------------

myData %>%
  left_join(myMap) %>%
  mutate(Name=as.character(Name),
         Name=ifelse(is.na(Name), ID, Name)) -> dplyr_myData

## Joining by: "ID"

dplyr_myData

##   ID Sum Name
## 1  1  10    a
## 2  2  20    b
## 3  3  30    c
## 4  4  40    d
## 5  5  50    e
## 6  6  60    6
## 7  7 700    g
## 8  5 200    e

# base --------------------------------------------------------------------

base_myData <- merge(myData, myMap, all.x=TRUE)
base_myData$Name <- as.character(base_myData$Name)
base_myData$Name <- ifelse(is.na(base_myData$Name),
                           base_myData$ID, base_myData$Name)

base_myData

##   ID Sum Name
## 1  1  10    a
## 2  2  20    b
## 3  3  30    c
## 4  4  40    d
## 5  5  50    e
## 6  5 200    e
## 7  6  60    6
## 8  7 700    g
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#1.9.5+
setkey(setDT(myData), ID)[myMap, Name:=i.Name][is.na(Name),
              Name:= as.character(ID)]
#   ID Sum Name
#1:  1  10    a
#2:  2  20    b
#3:  3  30    c
#4:  4  40    d
#5:  5  50    e
#6:  5 200    e
#7:  6  60    6
#8:  7 700    g
```

NOTE: As commented by @Arun, in the devel version `v1.9.5`, we can also set the key as an argument inside `setDT`, i.e. `setDT(myData, key='ID')`

Comment: In 1.9.5+ you can do: `setDT(myData, key="ID")[ ... ]`